# Constructing a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am trying to construct a continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued function $f$ satisfying the following properties:

1) $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0, b]$

2) $f(0) = 0$ and $f(b) = b$

3) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f'(x) = \infty$

4) $f'(b) \in (0,1)$

5) There exists some "special" value $a \in (0,b)$ such that $f'(a) = 1$, but $f'(x) > 1$ for all $x < a$, and $f'(x) < 1$ for all $x > a$.

6) $f$ is concave down

Ideally I want to be able to choose this $a$ freely, so that any $a$ I choose will satisfy these 5 requirements.

Comment: Not sure... take, for example $f(x) = b^{1-p}x^p$, where $p \in (0,1)$. The derivative at $0$ is infinity. It also satisfies (1) through (4), but not (5) (my biggest concern). Maybe my notation is wrong.

Comment: It looks like your example (in the comments) works for the case $p=0.5$.

Comment: You want $f'(b) \in (0,1)$ and $f'(a) =1$, then there is a contradiction here. May be you want to let $f'(b) \in (0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, it does. But I'd like to be able to freely choose a value $a$ which will modify the function to satisfy (5).

Comment: I'm not sure I see a contradiction with that statement. If $b=100$ in my previous comments, then $a = 32.097...$ is a counterexample to your contradiction.

Comment: What is the context of this problem, and what work have you done on it so far?

Answer (score 1):

How about a function of the form $f(x) = Cx^\alpha$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Then $f^\prime(x) = C\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ and since $\alpha - 1 < 0$
we would have 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f^\prime(x) = \infty$$

Now you must choose $\alpha$ and $C$ to satisfy
$$a = (1/(C\alpha))^{1/(\alpha - 1)}$$
since $f^\prime(a) = 1$.
and
$$b = C^{1/(1 - \alpha)}$$
since $f(b) = b$.

To satisfy both of these we note that from the above we get
$$b/a = \alpha^{1/(\alpha - 1)}$$
The above equation can be solved for $\alpha$ iff $b/a > e$,
where $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm. This follows
since $$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0} \alpha^{1/(\alpha - 1)} = \infty$$
and $$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1} \alpha^{1/(\alpha - 1)} = e$$

Once you have solved for $\alpha$, and then you can solve for
$C$ since $C = b^{1-\alpha}$.

This particular form won't work if $b/a < e$ so this isn't a complete
solution yet.

Comment: Good analysis. I'm interested in the case when $b/a < e$. Particularly, I'm interested when $b=100$ and $a = 60$.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to explain for which values of $a$ your proposed functions do in fact solve your problem.

Note that the function $g(x)=x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ is continous on $[0,1]$ with $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} g(x)=e^{-1}$. It follows by the intermediate value theorem that for any $v$ in $(0,\frac{1}{e})$ there exists $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f(c)=v$.

Let $f_p(x) = b^{1-p}x^p$ for some $p$ in $(0,1)$ (as you suggested). Then as you said these functions satisfy (1) - (4) of your conditions. We will show that for each $a$ in $(0,b)$ there exists $p$ such that $f_p$ satisfies (5). We have $f'(x)=b^{1-p}px^{p-1}$ so that $f_p'(a) =1$ if and only if $\frac{a}{b} = p^{\frac{1}{1-p}}$. So if $\frac{a}{b}$ is in $(0,\frac{1}{e})$ it follows as noted above that there does exist $p$ in $(0,1)$ such that $p^{\frac{1}{1-p}}=\frac{a}{b}$ and hence for that $p$ we do have $f'_p(a)=1$ as required.

Since $a^b$ is usually defined (for real numbers $a$ and $b$ where $a>0$) as $e^{b\ln(a)}$  someone might object to the definition of $g$ above saying that it is not defined at $0$. To avoid this one can define $g$ to be the function defined by
$$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ l l}0 & \text{if $x=0$}\\
  e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}} & \text{if $x \in (0,1)$}\\
  e^{-1} & \text{if $x=1$.} \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: I see what you're saying; however, take $b=100$ and $a=60$. So we solve $0.6 = p^{1-p}$, so $p = 0.4166...$. Now, $f'(60) = (0.4166)(0.6)^{(-0.5834)} = 0.5612 \neq 1$.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have edited to fix the problem. However now it is only a partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to treat the case $b=1.$ Suppose $0<a<1.$ Idea: Construct a positive strictly decreasing continuous $g$ on $(0,1]$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) =\infty, g(a) = 1,$ and $\int_0^1g = 1.$ If there is such a $g,$ we can set $f(x) =\int_0^x g.$ Then $f(0)=0, f(1) = 1.$ By the FTC, $f'(x) = g(x) > 0, x\in (0,1],$ so $f$ is strictly increasing. Also $f'(a)=g(a) = 1.$ And because $f' = g$ is strictly decreasing, $f$ is strictly concave.

Define a family of functions $g_c, c \ge 0,$ as follows: On $(0,a], g_c(x) = 1 + c(a-x)/\sqrt x.$ On $[a,1],$ simply let the graph of $g_c$ be the line segment connecting $(a,1)$ and $(1,1/2).$ (Good to draw a picture.) Now $\int_a^1 g_c = 3/4-3a/4.$ The integral $\int_0^a g_c $ is a continuous function of $c$ that equals $a$ when $c=0$ and $\to \infty$ as $c\to \infty.$ It follows that $\int_0^1g_c$ takes on all values in $[a + 3/4-3a/4,\infty).$ Because $a + 3/4-3a/4 < 1,$ there exists $c>0$ such that $\int_0^1g_c = 1.$ (It's not hard to evaluate $c$ directly, but it's a little messy and I didn't want to just throw it out at you and walk away with a smirk.) OK, that particular $g_c$ is the $g$ we are after and the proof is finished.